How to achieve message template highlighting for structured logging?
When using the Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger<T> with message templates for structured logging, Visual Studio highlights the message template "named holes"/parameters like this (see {Address}):

Is it possible to achieve the same highlighting effect at the call site for one of your own methods?
If so, how? What are the mechanics behind the highlighting?

Background (but I'm curius in the general case):
We're using an exception filter method as discussed here, like this:
public static class LoggerExtensions
{
    public static bool LogExceptionNoCatch<T>(this ILogger<T> logger, Exception exception, string? message, params object?[] args)
    {
        logger.LogError(exception, message, args);
        return false;
    }
    // ...
}

However, when using this extension method there is no highlighting indicating that message templates is being used:


I've tried to follow msdn tutorial and nothing is highlighted. Is it your project? Can you post [mcve], perhaps I am doing something wrong. Also check which VS extension you have installed.

Related

Which Visual Studio you use? Perhaps it's Visual Studio Code? That's explain why my attempt with Visual Studio 2022 failed.

I'm using "regular" Visual Studio 2022.

Try declaring your extension method as public static bool LogExceptionNoCatch<T>(this ILogger<T> logger, Exception exception, [StringSyntax(StringSyntaxAttribute.CompositeFormat)] string? message, params object?[] args) ..., this doesn't highlight anything for me, but it likely should for you, since you see a part of composite string highlighted with green color in first screenshot.

Do you have Resharper installed? Then it could be one of resharper attributes. Similarly to above, you need to attribute arguments of your own methods to get highlighing happens.

Thanks @Sinatr! Turning off Resharper indeed turns off the highlighting. And adding the [StructuredMessageTemplate] attribute enables highlighting to new methods. (I'm hoping that Microsoft will add StringSyntaxAttribute.MessageTemplate in order to avoid a dependence on Jetbrains/Resharper.)

It turns out that it is Resharper that does the highlighting for me, as suggested in a comment by @Sinatr. (I should have checked before posting.)
Adding the Jetbrains' StructuredMessageTemplateAttribute at the message parameter adds highlighting at the call site.
public static bool LogExceptionNoCatch<T>(this ILogger<T> logger, Exception exception, [JetBrains.Annotations.StructuredMessageTemplate] string? message, params object?[] args)
{
    logger.LogError(exception, message, args);
    return false;
}

so that it looks like this:

I can't help wodering what makes Resharper do highlighting on the Microsoft ILogger members though...

The Resharper is likely supports StringSyntaxAttribute, which should be present in LogError method implementation starting from .Net 7.
